# Tkinter TreeView remove dotbox highlight

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Hi I'm trying to remove the dotbox hightlight when i select a certain row of my TreeView, It highlights the text of the first columns that also contains a image:

[image]

I'm a newbie, but guessing that is happening because the first column is not created with the constructor and is separate to the other columns as you can see in the following example:

```
    f = ttk.Frame(master)
    f.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.dataCols = ('Project Name','Status', 'Cores', 'Added date/time')
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=self.dataCols)
    self.tree.grid(in_=f, row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('#1', text='Project Name', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('#2', text='Status', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('#3', text='Cores', anchor='center')
    self.tree.heading('#4', text='Added date/time', anchor='center')
    self.tree.column('#0', anchor='center', width=1)
    self.tree.column('#1', anchor='w')
    self.tree.column('#2', anchor='center')
    self.tree.column('#3', anchor='center')
    self.tree.column('#4', anchor='center')
    f.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    f.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    style = ttk.Style(master)
    style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=38)
```

It was implemented this way to allow a image as a column value.

**Edit**:

This is how I'm inserting rows to the Treeview.

```
    self.tree.insert('', 'end', image=auxiliary_classes.global_data.img_container[obj.name],
                     value=obj.get_list())
```

**Edit:**

```
    style = ttk.Style(master)
    style.theme_use('clam')

    style.layout('nodotbox.Treeview.Item',
                 [('Treeitem.padding',
                   {'children': [('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                                 ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                                 ('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})],
                    'sticky': 'nswe'})])

    style.configure(style='nodotbox.Treeview')
```

**Edit:**

This code did the trick!

```
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.layout("Treeview.Item",
                 [('Treeitem.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
                     [('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                      ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                      # ('Treeitem.focus', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': '', 'children': [
                      ('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                      # ]})
                      ],
                                        })]
                 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dotbox highlight is part of the style so you can remove it by changing the layout of the treeview's style.

The default layout is

```
[('Treeitem.padding',
  {'children': [('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
    ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
    ('Treeitem.focus',
     {'children': [('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})],
      'side': 'left',
      'sticky': ''})],
   'sticky': 'nswe'})]
```

and the dotbox is `'Treeitem.focus'`, so if you create a custom layout without it, then it will no longer be visible:

```
style = ttk.Style(master)

style.layout('nodotbox.Treeview.Item', 
             [('Treeitem.padding',
               {'children': [('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                 ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                 ('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})],
                'sticky': 'nswe'})])

tree.configure(style='nodotbox.Treeview')
```

**EDIT**: Full example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(master)

style.layout('nodotbox.Treeview.Item', 
             [('Treeitem.padding',
               {'children': [('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                 ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                 ('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})],
                'sticky': 'nswe'})])

tk.Label(master, text='Default layout').pack()
tree1 = ttk.Treeview(master, columns=('a', 'b'))
tree1.insert('', 'end', text='item 1', values=('a', 'b'))
tree1.insert('', 'end', text='item 2', values=('a', 'b'))
tree1.pack()

tk.Label(master, text='No dotbox').pack()
tree2 = ttk.Treeview(master, style='nodotbox.Treeview', columns=('a', 'b'))
tree2.insert('', 'end', text='item 1', values=('a', 'b'))
tree2.insert('', 'end', text='item 2', values=('a', 'b'))
tree2.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result, wasn't the desired checkout what my treeview looks like right now https://imgur.com/a/NnRH2, check tha the highlight still exist.

Comment: Which OS are you using? It works for me on Linux and Windows.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7, it's kind of weird, because even your default layout looks weird when i set it, any guess why?

Comment: Maybe it is because it is the layout of the default linux theme. Can you try with the theme 'clam' (do `style.theme_use('clam')` before changing the layout) ?

Comment: Hi!, sorry for the delay, i've tried it with the theme 'clam', but the dotbox still happens to appear :/, check edit above to see the code that i used.

Comment: I remove the dotbox with the code on my last edit, thanks!

Comment: @divancontreras I have added an full example to my answer, I hope it clarifies it for you.